# How can I fix my asyncio python 3 program to read a button push on GPIO26?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, gpio

I'm trying to write simple python 3 program to read pushed button, that runs with ansycio. I have button connected to ground and GPIO26.
I've wrote programm, but it doesn't work.
Here it is:

```
import asyncio
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
BUTTON_PIN = 26


def button_pushed(_):
    print("button pushed!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(BUTTON_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_PIN, GPIO.FALLING, callback=button_pushed, bouncetime=10)

    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        loop.close()
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

What did I've done wrong?

I've tried without ansycio, it worked

```
import  RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def button_pushed(_):
    print('Button pushed')
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
try:
    GPIO.add_event_detect(26, GPIO.FALLING, callback=button_pushed)
    input('press enter')
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Why did you change `pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN` to `pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP`?  If you're looking for a falling edge, you don't want the pin pulled down, do you?  Also, there is no point to using asyncio when you do not define more than one Task.

Comment: "GPIO.PUD_UP" helped. I have to read documentaton more carefully. Thank you

Comment: You have Linux kernel behind, right? Whynot using `gpio-keys` module with proper Device Tree stanza and then consider it as a normal key in the OS?